# Can't bevel - Invalid boundary region to join faces - edge dissolve

Tags: modifiers, edges

I have the tray model as shown below. **[Image 1]**

Here is the blender file: [Trays](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c36sidadi3104q6/trays4%20cut.blend?dl=0)

Which was created by boolean subtracting the spaces.

I want to bevel the top edges, but the booleans left over extra edges **[Image 2]**, so the top is not a 'single face', and this ruins the bevel (with 'Clamp Overlap' off). **[Image 3]**

I have tried Dissolve Edges, but blender says "Invalid boundary region to join faces". I have tried removing double vertices. And I have tried scaling in Z axis to 0 to ensure all vertices are on exactly the same plane, then Dissolve Edges - still doesn't work.

How do I make the entire top 'one face' so that my bevel will work? Or another solution?

Thanks!

[image: Can't bevel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer thanks to advice on: [Can't bevel an NGon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52842/cant-bevel-an-ngon)

I learned that blender 'needs' the extra edges, and that having an ngon is a bad idea. So I created all the extra geometry (by extruding along normals and manipulating some vertices/faces), and then the bevel works:

(I also now created the whole mesh without doing a boolean operation).

[image]

[image]