# Can't bevel an NGon

Tags: edges

I want to achieve a uniform bevel on the top surface of my model as shown in the first image below, but the bevel is spoiled by 2 'extra edges' joining the top edge loops (image 2).

No matter what method I use (see other images), blender always leave behind the 2 extra edges.

Why are the 2 edges there, can I get rid of them, or how otherwise can I achieve the uniform bevel?

NB1: I have tried Dissolve Edges, but once you get down to 2, blender says 'Invalid boundary region to join faces'.

NB2: I can't use mirror modifier because this is a simplified example of my more complex model.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a solution:
[image: beveled and non beveled meshes]
But you'll need to adjust Bevel width correctly so that nothing overlaps.

Comment: Thank you @lemon I think this is what I want - managed to get a good-looking bevel with this geometry. However, one small problem, see my next post.

Comment: Look here : https://gyazo.com/b93b0b1cd0a20be55b263534101fc8fd from left to right : 1/ make the simple flat shape 2/ take the inside extrude E and make face F 3/ take the outside and the same 4/ add the bevel

Comment: Thank you, I've got it working now! Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud really try to keep your topology as quads (polygons made of 4 vertices) to avoid issues down the line.

[image]

Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while **Right Clicking** on the edge to select the whole outer edge loop.

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to [Bevel](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html?highlight=bevel#bevel) that edge. And refine it to your needs.

[image]

Then just repeat on the inner loop:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't get rid of them. 
Blender needs those edges to correctly draw geometry.

So if you need to get the bevel shown in the first image on the right side, you need geometry like in the 4th image. Then select the edge loops that you need to bevel, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and drag the mouse to achieve bevel width, scroll <kbd>MMB</kbd> or enter a value to increase amount of segments, then press <kbd>LMB</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm your bevel.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, I managed to get a bevel this way, but it ends up looking like the left side of my first image... the right side is neater :)