# Box with double bevel edges

Tags: modeling

Im trying to model the box of the amp shown. I bevel the edges of the box

[image: Amp showing the conflictive zone]

When I try to cut the hole, I bevel again the edges to get the round curve marked as "painfull zone". And no way to get a decent result.

When I smooth the box, geometry gets ugly. Tried applying some faces flat, but never get the correct result.

Here is my mesh:

[image: Incorrect mesh]

Can somebody point me the right way to get the correct result?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Probably the same as this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52842/cant-bevel-an-ngon/52845#52845

Comment: Following the steps you suggested I can get a better result, but inner bevel of the box is not correct because curve is too big.

You have to consider that outer bevel is big, very rounded corners and they are near of inner corners that should have a very small bevel. That is because Im going crazy.

Comment: How did you create your outer bevel?

Comment: I added a cube --> edit mode --> selected all edges --> bevel. Im yet fighting with this. None of the posted solutions worked for a correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to ensure you have:

- face loops flowing around the edge (illustrated in black)
- the bevel edges you have created should be continued to flow across the surface (illustrated in red)
- and you should replace the n-gons/tris with a 5-pole that is sufficiently far from the edge that any distortion will be minimal (illustrated in blue).

[image]

Sorry I don't have time to do a full tutorial.  Hopefully the image will give you some ideas.

Comment: Well I have used what you suggested with a more or less nice result for the covers of the corners. I had to model the box of the amp with the errors. Fortunely they have been covered.

But dont know if my method was correct. I had to cut loops by hand. And I think they will be noticed in the final render.

If you know an automated method to do loops as you shown, will be helpfull.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep your topology as quads. Using Ngons is only going to give you trouble when you want to subdivide.

Start with a cube.

Inset the top face.

Extrude the center face and bring it down on the Z axis to get the basic shape of the box.

[image]

Select the outer loop edge (press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and Right Click with the mouse) and bevel it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>)

Do the same with the inner edge loop.

[image]

Then select the inner edges and bevel them as well.

[image]